# Odoo XML-RPC API: many2one fields are always empty

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I'm trying to get, through xmlrpc api, product.attribute.line by product_tmpl_id but its many2one fields are always empty(for example attribute_id).

I don't understand because many2one fields are always empty.

Should I change something in Odoo-8 configuration?

Regards

Comment: Check that "other.object.name" is empty or not. If it is empty then it won't show you anything.